# getting session user_id in a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have "updated_by" field in most of my models. I need to update this field with the current user id.

What is the best way to obtain session user is in a Model?
Where can I put logic to populate the "updated_by" field for any models which respond_to that method?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to store the current_user in the ApplicationController. You can handle there any logic you want (read the cookie, redirect to the home page if the user have not cookie etc). So **storing the current_user variable in the ApplicationController let you access to that from every model or controller you want.** 
 Check this link http://niczsoft.com/2010/03/rails-current-user/